# KTY82/220 Temperature sensor terminals

Tags: sensor, temperature, nxp

I wanted to use NXP KTY82/220(https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/KTY82_SER.pdf) temperature sensor for my circuit. But I could not see which are the terminals for Vdd, GND and Analog Out in datasheet. Can any one suggest.

I have modified the circuit as following.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding the type of sensor. The datasheet explains:

> The temperature sensors in the KTY82 series have a positive temperature coefficient of
>   resistance and are suitable for use in measurement and control systems.

They are a silicon resistor with a positive temperature coefficient. There are no active components internally so you do not apply DC power as shown in your schematic.

[image]

*Figure 1. Connection details.*

Your circuit should monitor the resistance between pins 1 and 2. Polarity doesn't matter.

Pin 3 is provided for mounting stability. The pad it is connected to should be isolated from the rest of the circuit.

Comment: You can find some general details and reference circuits on the manufacturer application note [Silicon sensors for temperature measurement](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/243481/KTY-Philips.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have modified the circuit. I want to measure the surface temperature of a brush less motor. Could you please suggest which type of temperature sensor are suitable for the application.?

Comment: Here my idea is to use a SMD temp sensor on my PCB which is near(5 mm gap) to the motor. My question is, Is there any cheap temp sensor which can be surface mounted on the motor body to measure temperature accurately?

Comment: DS18S20 perhaps